# Centring CardViews in Recyclerview

Tags: android

There's my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

His layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:context="com.example.programista.dobra_robimy.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/list_frag"
            class="com.example.programista.dobra_robimy.FragmentListAlarms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentListAlarms:

```
public class FragmentListAlarms extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView alarmsRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_alarms, container, false);

        String[] alarmsNames = new String[Alarms.AlarmsList.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < alarmsNames.length; i++) {
            alarmsNames[i] = Alarms.AlarmsList[i].getName();
        }

        TextAdapter adapter = new TextAdapter(alarmsNames);
        alarmsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        alarmsRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return alarmsRecycler;
    }
}
```

His layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/alarms_recycler"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Adapter:

```
class TextAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] array;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
            super(v);
            cardView = v;
        }
    }

    public TextAdapter(String[] names) {
        this.array = names;
    }

    @Override
    public TextAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int    viewType) {
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        TextView textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        textView.setText(array[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return array.length;
    }
}
```

And cardview layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And my problem: I want to make `CardViews` in centre point on my screen, but I am always getting something like that:
[screen shot from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvWbV.png)

I set gravity="centre" in every possibly place, but the CardViews are still sticked to left margin :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"//the more this value the less width of card view
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"//the more this value the less width of card view
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**EDIT**
As I know RecyclerView's items cannot be simply centred through setting *layout_gravity="center"* for parent view, but there is another way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">   

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <TextView/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, i see , but cant i just center it somewhere ?

Comment: You can set parent layout for your CardView (for example, LinearLayout) and then centre the cardview. Check my edited answer.